# How can I access My.Settings from a module within the website?

Tags: asp.net, module

I added a module which will have common code accessed from most of my pages in an ASP.NET web application. I am unable to access My.Settings from the module. What am I missing?

The problem: **My.Settings.SQLServerName** does not work.

This is the first time I've tried a module. I usually use a class with shared function on the root of the site. The module is place in a special folder App_Code. Should I remove the module and place it in the root of the site?

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Public Function GetConnection(Optional ByVal ThisDatabase As String = "") As String

    Dim sConn As String = "Data Source=/ThisServer/;Initial Catalog=/ThisDatabase/;User Id=/ThisUser/;Password=/ThisPassword/;"
    Dim sConnectionString As String = ""
    Dim sServer As String = ""
    Dim sDatabase As String = "ProjectMaster"
    Dim sUser As String = ""
    Dim sPassword As String = ""

    If Len(ThisDatabase) > 0 Then
        sDatabase = ThisDatabase
    End If

    sConnectionString = Replace(sConn, "/ThisServer/", My.Settings.SQLServerName)
    sConnectionString = Replace(sConnectionString, "/ThisDatabase/", sDatabase)
    sConnectionString = Replace(sConnectionString, "/ThisUser/", "UserName")
    sConnectionString = Replace(sConnectionString, "/ThisPassword/", "UserPassword")

    Return sConnectionString

End Function
```

I need access to the settings in the project within the module.

Comment: Continue using the App_Code folder. I think you'll have to add a using statement at the top of the page to access your other class, or make your class static (careful). You can also access settings that are in the web.config file, which is a common approach, and you will be able to change the setting without changing any code.

Comment: @wazz When I move the function to a module in the App_Code folder the public function is no longer available to the code. I find no Imports/Using statement available to make the function available to the page.

Comment: What is the name of the "module" file? Add the main details of the code in the file.

Comment: @wazz - The module name is MyCode. Sorry, I don't understand _"Add the main details of the code in the file."_

Comment: I meant to say, what's the name of the class file, with the extension. Add the code from that file to your question above.

Comment: @wazz -This is not a class but a module. This is place where subroutines and functions are stored for use on any page. It's easy to place a module at the root of the site and all compiles properly. But if I take the same module and move it to the App_Code folder I loose the ability to access the AppSettings variables from the subroutines and functions.